# Get uploaded file's full client path webservice c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, jquery-file-upload

Is there any api or tools to get client full path of uploaded files in asp.net?
I am using jquery and c# webservice to upload files.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Could you please elaborate.

Comment: Azhar I need to get the name of the client's pc's folder from where file is uploaded. So that I can use the folder name for my other tasks.

Comment: Thanks Menno for your response. I need any alternative of this. Can you help me?

Comment: Even if you could do this, what are you intending to do when you get a path like `/home/users/pk/uploadedfile.txt`? (This is a subtle hint that you don't want to be doing this, even if you think you do).

Comment: Philip thanks for your quick response. Like you said in /home/users/pk/uploadedfile.txt, when i get all this path then i need to insert pk in one column of database. I need the parent folder of file as well for client requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this information is available to you. A long time ago Internet Explorer included the local path when uploading files, but it stopped doing that a long time ago, as a security measure.

What other tasks would require the local path of the file on the user's system?

Comment: Thanks for you response Menno. I have a requirement to get file container client folder to insert to database. So is there any other way to get the folder name using any type of things.